# Getting the ObjectGUID of the current user

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a simple and fast way to retrieve the **ObjectGUID** of the current user **without using a modul** on a domain-joined computer.

By using a modul I am able to retrieve the ObjectGUID by using the following command:

```
( Get-ADUser -Identity $env:USERNAME | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ObjectGUID ).GUID
```

The desired result does look like this:

```
0f6697f5-f9d4-4883-afa0-0458c02090b2
```

On my research I did find ways to retreive the SID. e.g.:
[How to Find Security Identifier (SID) of User in Windows](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/84467-find-security-identifier-sid-user-windows.html#:%7E:text=OPTION%20SIX-,To%20Find%20SID%20of%20All%20Users%20using%20%22Get%2DWmiObject%22,command%20prompt%2C%20and%20press%20Enter.)

I will need this in a client-side script, running unattended.

- It should not need admin-rights.
- It would be perfect, if it would not be necessary to contact a domain-controller.
- I would need the same for the current's computer GUID.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the GUID for the current user (assuming the script is actually being executed as that user and not local system, a service account or such) the following should do the trick.

```
[guid]::New(([adsisearcher]"SamAccountName=$env:USERNAME").FindOne().Properties.objectguid[0]).Guid
```

The equivalent for the computer object could be something like this

```
[guid]::New(([adsisearcher]"SamAccountName=$env:COMPUTERNAME`$").FindOne().Properties.objectguid[0]).Guid
```

I believe both need to be able to contact a domain controller to work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I like this. Do you think there is also a way to get the GUIDs without asking the DC?

Comment: is there a reason you don't want it contacting the DC? Since GUID is a 128 bit hexadecimal value, that helps uniquely identify an object in a forest, its only for ADUC. You do have your SID that's attached to your user accounts for user permissions and your MachineGUID. Regarding your question thought, have you tried using TaskScheduler to run on the users context?

Comment: The script passes the GUID to a software, which uses this data.
I want this process to be as independent as possible and does not rely on a connection to the DC.
I did find the GUID in the clients-registry and therefore I think it must be locally available.
Maybe through WMI?

Comment: I can't help but think that the DC connection shouldn't necessarily be needed more than once for the scenario you're describing, say for instance at the time the software and/or script is deployed to the user/computer. But yes, I'd certainly assume there would be plenty of _"GUID-artifacts"_ to be found locally with a lil bit of digging.

Comment: if you found it in the clients registry, why not check to see if its stored in the same place on a different machine? You can just query the registry if that's the case

Comment: The path for the found User-GUID "HKLM::\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-********-*********-**********-500\GUID" does not look relieable to me and maybe adds other problems.

Comment: @notjustme I think I will take the [adsisearcher] solution and move on. I will accept it as answer. Thank you.